# Если из полного названия театра удаляется одно слово, что будет с прописными?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Московский драматический театр имени А. С. Пушкина.

Если остался "московский театр имени Пушкина", как быть с московским?

Без московского - знаю: Театр имени Пушкина.

Comment: Впереди, значит с прописной. И Театр, и Пушкинский, и Московский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректна прописная.

189. В официальных составных названиях органов власти, учреждений, организаций, научных, учебных и зрелищных заведений, обществ, политических партий и объединений **с прописной буквы пишется первое слово и входящие в состав названия имена собственные, а также первое слово включаемых в них названий других учреждений и организаций,** напр. **Государственная Третьяковская галерея, Государственный академический Большой театр, Московский Художественный академический театр,** Государственный Русский музей (**и неофициальные их названия: Третьяковская галерея, Большой театр, Художественный театр, Русский музей);**

См.: Академический справочник.