# «Победа» со Знаком качества». Нужно ли "знак" писать с заглавной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

**«Победа» со Знаком качества.** «Победа» — это танкер.
Словарь дает *Знак качества* с заглавной....

Answer (score 1):

flossyU, Вам встретился ОЧЕНЬ умный словарь!

Я обыскалась в нахождении правила, пришла на поклон к Грамоте.ру...

**[Вопрос № 214144](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=214144)**

> Уважаемая Справка! В третий раз задаю вопрос! Как в СССР писали
> названия: Государственный Знак Качества, Российский Морской Регистр
> Судоходства, Всероссийский Совет Народного Хозяйства (я имею в виду
> прописные буквы)?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Первые слова в этих названиях пишутся с большой буквы:
>
> *Государственный знак качества, Российский морской регистр судоходства, Всероссийский совет народного хозяйства*.

А тут уже действует другое правило: если в названии убирают первое слово, то прописная переходит на второе или далее:

[Московский драматический театр имени А. С. Пушкина - Драматический театр имени А. С. Пушкина - Театр имени А. С. Пушкина.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431532/%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8)

То же распространяется и на *Знак качества,* если опущено слово *Государственный.*

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, зависит от контекста. Если вы говорите о танкере, получившем Знак качества, — тогда с прописной. А если смеетесь над его качеством — то со строчной.

Comment: я б его закавычила...

Comment: Это было бы ошибкой!